# DB Context results show "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" from inherited class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api, dbcontext

I'm trying to retrieve the database context in my controller from Model A that's connected to a table in the database, but the results keep erring out due to another Model B that inherits from Model A. It includes additional properties that aren't in the database, and doesn't overwrite any of the properties from Model A, just extra properties.

As well, I'm trying to utilize Model B within my controller and without getting the context to show up for Model A (since it's a subclass of Model A), the whole controller isn't functioning.

My application runs ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API, SQL Server 2012 and IIS Express.

I've seen several solutions for other questions similar to this one say to place "[NotMapped]" above Model B and it's additional properties. I've tried that and it hasn't worked. It still shows the error in the title.

I've seen other solutions say to ignore Model B in the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) by putting "modelBuilder.Ignore()". This does cast away the error my initial error, but brings another one forth which is "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ModelB' because this type is not included in the model for the context".

Database Context Class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DT.Models;

namespace DT.Models
{
    public class DTContext : DbContext
    {
        public DTContext(DbContextOptions<DTContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<ModelA> ModelAs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ModelA>().ToTable("ModelA");
            //modelBuilder.Ignore<ModelB>();
        }
    }
}
```

Model A Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DT.Models
{
    [Description("GET or DELETE using Id")]
    public class ModelA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HotfixID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ExtendedDescription { get; set; }
        public string BugTrackCases { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }
        public DateTime HotfixDate { get; set; }
        public string HotfixLocation { get; set; }
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public List<DeploySite> DeploySites { get; set; }
        public List<FBCase> BugTrackCaseList { get; set; }
        public int? OriginalId { get; set; }
        public string CaseType { get; set; }
        public bool HasSQL { get; set; }
        public bool HasConfig { get; set; }
        public bool HasLibraries { get; set; }
        public bool HasWebApps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model B Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DT.Models
{
    [NotMapped]
    public class ModelB : ModelA
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool Complete { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ModelA Controller (only constructor)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DT.Models;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace DT.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/modela")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ModelAsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DTContext _context;

        public ModelAsController(DTContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
     }
}
```

Instead of seeing all the ModelAs in the result of _context in the constructor, that's when I see the error message.

But when I uncomment the "modelBuilder.Ignore()" in the Database Context, in my console I see the error I described before saying "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ModelB' because this type is not included in the model for the context". So I can't ignore it since it accesses the data from the database.

Comment: Please show code for ModelA

Comment: @BattlFrog I added it

Comment: One thing I have noticed, I think this line:         protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  should actually be:         protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by putting all my additional properties from ModelB to ModelA, so that I won't need to use ModelB. This now solves the context issue as well as utilizing ModelB, since we won't need to utilize it anymore.

ModelA Class (updated)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DT.Models
{
    [Description("GET or DELETE using Id")]
    public class ModelA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HotfixID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ExtendedDescription { get; set; }
        public string BugTrackCases { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }
        public DateTime HotfixDate { get; set; }
        public string HotfixLocation { get; set; }
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public List<DeploySite> DeploySites { get; set; }
        public List<FBCase> BugTrackCaseList { get; set; }
        public int? OriginalId { get; set; }
        public string CaseType { get; set; }
        public bool HasSQL { get; set; }
        public bool HasConfig { get; set; }
        public bool HasLibraries { get; set; }
        public bool HasWebApps { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool Complete { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```